# How demanding is fast device context flushing in wxPython

Tags: python, video, wxpython

I am creating a custom video player. So I have to draw a bitmap to `wx.BufferedDC()` minimally 24 times per second. But I am observing CPU overload and other events slow up pretty badly. There is no flickering though.

Are there any tricks except `BufferedDC()` that I should be aware of?

My `wx.Frame()` is full screen and used as `ClientDC()`.

Should I switch to pygame for this? I would like to use wxPython because there will be some complicated interfaces involved. And I am still not sure whether I want to mix these two or not. I will most probably  end mixing them anyway.

I don't understand why is this drawing so CPU intensive. It shouldn't be. Is there any way to use hardware acceleration as in pygame?

Some code is here. Please note that it is violently pulled out of big project and there are many changes. Some of which include totally unacceptable programming practices. It is here for example of what I am trying to do. And that you can see if everything I use - like styles etc. is OK.

```
from cStringIO import StringIO
from thread import start_new_thread as thread
from time import time, sleep
import wx
import os

class Player (wx.Frame):
    frames      = []
    curframe    = 0
    fetched     = 0.0
    imgduration = 1/24.0
    path        = "Mov"
    opened      = 1
    canclose    = 0
    blockerase  = 0
    def __init__ (self):
        wx.Frame.__init__(self, None, -1, "Player", size=wx.GetDisplaySize(), style=wx.NO_FULL_REPAINT_ON_RESIZE | wx.CLIP_CHILDREN )
        thread(self._fetcher,())
        thread(self._play,())
        self.Bind(wx.EVT_CLOSE, self.OnClose)
        self.Bind(wx.EVT_ERASE_BACKGROUND, self.OnEraseBackground)
        self.SetBackgroundColour(wx.Colour(0, 0, 0))
        fsstyle = (wx.FULLSCREEN_NOTOOLBAR | wx.FULLSCREEN_NOSTATUSBAR | 
                  wx.FULLSCREEN_NOBORDER | wx.FULLSCREEN_NOCAPTION)
        self.ShowFullScreen(True, fsstyle)
        self.Raise()

    def OnEraseBackground (self, e):
        if self.blockerase: return
        e.Skip()

    def OnClose (self, e):
        self.opened = 0
        while self.canclose<0: sleep(0.02)
        e.Skip()

    def _draw (self):
        dc = wx.BufferedDC(wx.ClientDC(self))
        dc.BeginDrawing()
        dc.Clear()
        f = self.frames[self.curframe]
        dc.DrawBitmap(f, 0, 0)
        dc.EndDrawing()
        self.curframe += 1
        if self.curframe==len(self.frames): self.curframe = 0

    def _play (self):
        self.canclose -= 1
        drawdelay = 0.0
        while self.opened:
            while self.fetched<3 and self.opened: sleep(0.1)
            if not self.opened: break
            t = time()
            self._draw()
            if not self.opened: break
            drawdelay = (drawdelay+(time()-t))/2.0
            drawdelay = (drawdelay, self.imgduration)[drawdelay>self.imgduration]
            sleep(self.imgduration-drawdelay)
        self.canclose += 1

    def _fetcher (self):
        self.canclose -= 1
        l = os.listdir(self.path)
        l.sort()
        ll = len(l)
        t = time()
        self._fetch(l[0])
        loaddelay = time()-t
        x = 1
        print "Fetching"
        while self.opened:
            t = time()
            self._fetch(l[x])
            x += 1
            if x==ll: break
            loaddelay = (loaddelay+(time()-t))/2.0
            #print loaddelay
        self.canclose += 1
        print "End fetching"

    def _fetch (self, fname):
        w, h = self.GetSize()
        fname = os.path.join(self.path, fname)
        f = open(fname, "rb")
        data = f.read()
        f.close()
        img = wx.ImageFromStream(StringIO(data))
        img.Rescale(w, h)
        f = wx.BitmapFromImage(img)
        self.frames.append(f)
        self.fetched += self.imgduration
```

Comment: Can you put some functional example code to analyze?. Thanks

Comment: Not really. It's pretty useless if you don't know what is my goal. I'll write an example later if it is necessary. Just imagine looping through a list of wx.Bitmaps and drawing them onto BufferedDC with appropriate pause between drawings. It's not so simple, but it would have the same effect.

Comment: The user Mike Driscoll (http://stackoverflow.com/users/393194/mike-driscoll) have a blog and post a Media Player Like using MPlayerCtrl. This example id very usefull and simple, and maybe solve your problem. The respective link is: http://www.blog.pythonlibrary.org/2010/07/24/wxpython-creating-a-simple-media-player/

Comment: Unfortunately, no. I have a bunch of video frames saved as JPEG. So, what I am writing is kind of MJPEG, but it will contain an editor as well. So, no, ready made controls are useless to me.

Comment: Ok, these frames are separated on many jpeg images, and you need to show in 24 fps?

Comment: Exactly. See the code I posted, although using this for real will cause some problems beside slowdown. For example, if you unpack a video to JPEGs to test this into a folder, make sure it is short, because if you have a folder with thousands of files, well, os.listdir() will block until all names are found from disk. And, I just realized that my FPS, although meant to be 24is either extra slow, or some frames aren't never shown at all and this causes it to look as if it is.

Comment: i think it's better to use `wx.Timer`. `self.timer = wx.Timer(self); self.Bind(wx.EVT_TIMER, self.OnTimer, self.timer); self.timer.Start(1000/24.0)` and do the frame update in `OnTimer`. Do you think the delay may come from disk I/O? can you preload all frames and store it as numpy array?

Comment: @otterb :I thought so at first, but nothing slows until "playback" starts, i.e. the self._play() is causing event queue either to be inaccessible or is overflowing it. I am pretty sure IO is not a problem here as I got most of frames preloaded by the time "playback" starts. My experience with wx.Timer() is that it is unpredictable. I.e. it is not made to fire every X ms for sure, but as soon as possible when given time passed. As it uses events, it is processed by MainLoop() and depends on all other intermediate actions. But I may try, just out of curiosity, to see what will happen.